# Specify a reference to an Elixir function @spec in another decorating function @spec

Tags: types, elixir

Is there a way to reference the return type spec of a function in another function specs ?

```
defmodule Car do
  @spec beep(none()) :: String.t
  def beep do
    "beep"
  end

  @spec beep_log(none()) :: String.t
  def beep_log do
    IO.puts "beep log"
    beep
  end
end
```

Can the specs for beep_log be specified in something like this:

```
 @spec beep_log(none()) :: beep()
```

Comment: I too missed type references like `@return (see foo)` in YARD, but there's a good reason to not support this:  it can be common to have circular dependencies of input and return types due to `foo_to_bar` and `bar_to_foo` conversion functions.  A lot of times in Elixir these functions are in different Modules as `Foo.to_bar` and `Bar.to_foo`, which means it would become a compile order issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No way to do that without defining a new data type that both the functions will return. You can see an example of this pattern in the [docs for the `GenServer` module](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/GenServer.html), where an [`on_start`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/GenServer.html#t:on_start/0) type is defined and shared by `start/3` and `start_link/3`.

In your case, something like this would work:

```
defmodule Car do
  @type beep_return() :: String.t

  @spec beep(none()) :: beep_return()
  def beep do
    "beep"
  end

  @spec beep_log(none()) :: beep_return()
  def beep_log do
    IO.puts "beep log"
    beep
  end
end
```